# How to disable same origin policy in Chrome v81

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

It was working before but with the latest Chrome update (version 81), "--disable-web-security" won't work anymore and I can't log in to my web app locally.

[image: You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security]

I have been using this reference successfully before:
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: This seems like more of a https://superuser.com/ question

Comment: @Phil I'll post it there also